# 'System.Delegate._methodPtr' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'

Tags: vb.net

While trying to access the methodptr property of a delegate object, I am getting the error:

```
"System.Delegate._methodPtr' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'
```

,is there some method through which I can access this value and assign it to a variable?

Comment: **why** do you want to access it? It’s `Friend` for a reason.

Comment: is because its your friend `:D`, try to create a new `Instance`. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814319

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there some method through which I can access this value and assign it to a variable?

You can use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx)<sup>1</sup> to retrieve the value. However, you probably don’t want to do this: this value is `Friend` for a reason. It’s an implementation detail and you as a consumer of the framework have no right to access it directly: it may work, or it may break suddenly (e.g. when Microsoft distributes an update of the library). Your code also won’t work on alternative .NET implementations, such as Mono.

In particular, [this member is not documented in the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.aspx) and as such its presence or behaviour can’t be relied on.

---

<sup>1</sup> The following should do the trick:

```
Dim delegateType = yourDelegateObject.GetType()
Dim field = delegateType.GetField("_methodPtr", _
        BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
Dim methodPtr = DirectCast(field.GetValue(yourDelegateObject), IntPtr)
```

Untested, since I only have Mono and (as mentioned above) it won’t work here anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much Konrad Rudolph, It is really helpful